# How do I use 'if' condition inside a 'if' condition?

Tags: oracle, function, if-statement, plsql, oracle11g

I am trying to use 'if' condition inside a 'if' condition to create a function.
I know the syntax looks somewhat like below, but I am unable to do it in my code.

```
IF sales > (quota + 200) THEN
    bonus := (sales - quota)/4;
ELSE
    IF sales > quota THEN
        bonus := 50;
    ELSE
        bonus := 0;
    END IF;
END IF;
```

Below is the program I am trying to complete. Please help me with it.
Its a function to find phone bill amount wrt given number of calls
and plan Type

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION BILL(NUM_OF_CALLS NUMBER, PLAN_TYPE NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS :

    BILL_AMT NUMBER;
    MIN_1 NUMBER :=150;
    MIN_2 NUMBER :=1000;    

    BEGIN
    IF PLAN_TYPE:=150 THEN 
        IF NUM_OF_CALLS<150 THEN 
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1;
            ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 151 AND 250 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(NUM_OF_CALLS-150);
            ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 251 AND 400 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(100*1)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-250)*0.5;
            ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS>400 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(100*1)+(150*0.5)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-400)*0.3;
        END IF;
        ELSE PLAN_TYPE:=500 THEN
            IF NUM_OF_CALLS<1000 THEN 
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_2;
            ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_2+(NUM_OF_CALLS-1000)*0.50;
            ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS>1500 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_2+(500*0.50)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-1500)*0.25;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN BILL_AMT;

END;
```

Below are the errors

SQL> show error
Errors for FUNCTION BILL:

```
LINE/COL ERROR

11/14    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the
         following:
         . ( * @ % & = - + < / > at in is mod remainder not rem then
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset
         The symbol "* was inserted before "=" to continue.

22/22    PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "THEN" when expecting one of
         the following:
         * & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
         <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
         like4 likec between || multiset member submultiset

31/6     PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "IF" when expecting one of the
         following:
         ; <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier>
         current delete exists prior <a single-quoted SQL string>
```

Comment: it's seems a Pascal language , but := inside if are wrongs

Comment: It is Oracle PL SQL...

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Ed : posted the errors

Comment: @ClaudioDaffra, yes, PL/SQL was heavily influenced, at the syntax level at least, by Ada, which borrowed from Pascal as well as other influences.

Comment: sorry for downvoting, but to learn basic syntax and operators of language is the very minimum what you ought to do before asking question.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is directly in the error output.

PLSQL uses `:=` for assignation and `=` for comparison.  You are intermixing these operators and causing these errors.

Read the errors closely, they exactly describe the problem.

Hint: Add small amounts of logic at a time so that you know where your problems originate.  Each of us learns this at some point in time :)

Answer (score 0):

You can't

```
   ELSE PLAN_TYPE:=500 THEN
```

But you can

```
   ELSIF PLAN_TYPE =500 THEN
```

If I've got your logic flow figured out

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  FUNCTION BILL(NUM_OF_CALLS NUMBER, PLAN_TYPE NUMBER) RETURN NUMBER IS 

    BILL_AMT NUMBER;
    MIN_1    NUMBER :=150;
    MIN_2    NUMBER :=1000;    

 BEGIN
    IF PLAN_TYPE = 150 
    THEN 
        IF NUM_OF_CALLS<150 THEN 
            BILL_AMT  :=MIN_1;
        ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 151 AND 250 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(NUM_OF_CALLS-150);
        ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 251 AND 400 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(100*1)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-250)*0.5;
        ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS>400 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(100*1)+(150*0.5)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-400)*0.3;
        END IF;
    ELSIF PLAN_TYPE = 500 THEN
        IF NUM_OF_CALLS<1000 THEN 
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_2;
        ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_2+(NUM_OF_CALLS-1000)*0.50;
        ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS>1500 THEN
            BILL_AMT:=MIN_2+(500*0.50)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-1500)*0.25;
        END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN BILL_AMT;

END;
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure the `END IF;` closes the `IF NUM_OF_CALLS<150 THEN` and the following `ELSE` is related to the `IF PLAN_TYPE=150 THEN` (although it should be `ELSIF` not `ELSE`)

Comment: Yes, the formatting threw me. But you still cant ELSE <condition>... I've updated my answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE  
FUNCTION BILL(NUM_OF_CALLS NUMBER, PLAN_TYPE NUMBER) 
   RETURN NUMBER 
IS

    BILL_AMT NUMBER;
    MIN_1    NUMBER := 150;
    MIN_2    NUMBER := 1000;    

BEGIN
    IF PLAN_TYPE = 150 
    THEN 
       IF NUM_OF_CALLS<150 
       THEN 
          BILL_AMT:= MIN_1;
       ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 151 AND 250 
       THEN
          BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(NUM_OF_CALLS-150);
       ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 251 AND 400 
       THEN
          BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(100*1)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-250)*0.5;
       ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS>400 
       THEN
          BILL_AMT:=MIN_1+(100*1)+(150*0.5)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-400)*0.3;
       END IF;
    ELSIF PLAN_TYPE = 500 
    THEN
       IF NUM_OF_CALLS<1000 
       THEN 
          BILL_AMT:=MIN_2;
       ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS BETWEEN 1001 AND 1500 THEN
          BILL_AMT:=MIN_2+(NUM_OF_CALLS-1000)*0.50;
       ELSIF NUM_OF_CALLS>1500 THEN
          BILL_AMT:=MIN_2+(500*0.50)+(NUM_OF_CALLS-1500)*0.25;
       END IF;
    END IF;

    RETURN BILL_AMT;

END BILL;
```

Hope it helps...